# How to go to the next line in a begin description

Tags: description

How can I make it so that when a line gets too long it goes to the next line?

Comment: See the enumitem package. And next time please provide a full code example, makes it much clearer what you are talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to ensure that a description label can span multiple lines, you can make use of the `unboxed` style offered by the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
\item[description] here is the description of the label
\item[this is a very long description label this is a very long description label ] here is the description of the label here is the description of the label here is the description of the label
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to tweak this so that it doesn't indent?
To be clear, it gives me right now https://imgur.com/a/aoxqRuP but I'd like to not have an indent.

Comment: In your question you asked about a `description`, while the screenshot you show in your comment lookas like you actually used `itemize`. If this is the case, please post your question as a follow up question to this one and please also include a minimal example showing how you achieved this output.

Comment: I'm using description, see code below

`\begin{description}
[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=\parindent,font=\normalfont, style = unboxed]

\item[• Magret de canard (150-200g par personne)]
\item[• Riz]
\item[• Brocolis]
\item[• Ketchup, ail, gingembre, huile d'olive, sauce soja salée, vinaigre de balsamique, orange, miel de cuisine, poivre, piment espelette, thym, laurier]
\end{description}`

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that might be better suited to what you actually want to achieve. Just use itemize or use paragraphs instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
\bfseries
\item An extremely long description that is written in bold and so on which is long enough to wrap properly
\item Another item
\end{itemize}

Or you could just use paragraphs:

\paragraph{A very long item with lots of words in it and so on and then some normal text}

This text is normal
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\paragraph` is a 4th level heading, like `\section` it is just intended to be used after `\subsubsection`